# Remove duplicate data from an array in usin python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array with data and I notice that I have each data twice. Is there any method to remove the duplicate data to simplify the array content? Below is the code that I made in python:

```
import requests
import re
import bs4

r = requests.get("http://as.com/tag/moto_gp/a/")

r.raise_for_status()

html = r.text


matches = re.findall(r"http://motor\.as\.com/motor/\d+/\d+/\d+/motociclismo/\d+_\d+.html", html)

print (matches)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope your `matches` is a list.Then you can use simple method.

```
In [1]: a = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5]
In [2]: list(set(a))
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

For your code only one modification.

```
matches = list(set(re.findall(r"http://motor\.as\.com/motor/\d+/\d+/\d+/motociclismo/\d+_\d+.html", html)))
```

Comment: @SergeiLebedev You are right. It will work with all iterable.