# How do I stop a string from repeating in my array?

Tags: python, arrays, beautifulsoup

I have an array of strings (stock ticker symbols) that I have scraped from twitter. I scrape stock ticker symbols from one person's feed, however, sometimes the feed will have multiple tweets about the same stock ticker and will therefore repeat multiple times in my array. How do I stop the stock ticker from repeating in my array?

Here is my code

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

twiturl = "https://twitter.com/ACInvestorBlog"
twitpage = urllib.request.urlopen(twiturl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(twitpage,"html.parser")

tweets = [i.text for i in soup.select('a.twitter-cashtag.pretty-link.js-nav b')]
print(tweets)
```

here is what prints out

```
['AYTU', 'AYTU', 'AYTU', 'AYTU', 'INDU', 'JPM', 'BAC', 'INPX', 'MSFT', 'SPX', 'HMNY', 'YTEN', 'INPX', 'MACK', 'KDMN', 'AMBA', 'KDMN', 'KDMN', 'MACK']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate data from an array in usin python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373196/remove-duplicate-data-from-an-array-in-usin-python)

Answer (score 1):

use `set comprehension` instead of the `list comprehension` that you're using:

```
tweets = {i.text for i in soup.select('a.twitter-cashtag.pretty-link.js-nav b')}
```

you can transform your `set` to `list` using the code below, if you need to

```
tweets = list(tweets)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an empty dictionary.

In the loop, you can perform a check:

if the dictionary does not contain key of the current element then insert it to tweets and the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple check on each iteration of the for loop:

```
tweets = []
for i in soup.select('a.twitter-cashtag.pretty-link.js-nav b'):
    if i.text not in tweets:
        tweets.append(i.text)
print(tweets)
```